# How to query average value of data and round it to be two decimal points in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am learning the UDF calculation functions supported in Apache IoTDB, and I realized that when querying average values using "avg", seems like the whole average value will be queried out. I wonder can the average value be queried out, and to keep, for example, two decimal places using other UDF function in IoTDB?

I checked the official manual for all UDF functions I can found, but seems like there is no function that can both calculate the average value and to directly came back with two decimal points of the result. Hope anyone can refresh me with the new updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest master version of Apache IoTDB already has a `round` function. In this case, you can use `select round(avg(s1), 2) from root.db.d1`, so that two decimal places of average values can be kept and directly queried. This official release is in IoTDB Version 1.2, and you can package it yourself in github and try this function.